# Tomcat StandardClassLoader slow at startup

Tags: java, tomcat, classloader

I have a tomcat installation in a windows enviroment using a raid1 array.
Tomcat takes a lot of time starting, looking into its logs it takes a long time to load all classes in method org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader.

The strange thing is that tomcat load takes 80s if I start it just after windows load, otherwise It take 20s and I think this is would be an acceptable time.

How to speed up this load? Can it be connected to the raid configuration?

Comment: Any webapps on the tc?

Comment: Of course, an Spring + Hibernate web app. I can understand it can take some second to load, but what a big difference between a startup load and a delayed start!